# Cast from '[Any]?' to unrelated type '[String : String?]' always fails issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I use this code to store app settings via UserDefaults:

```
var appSettings: [String: String?] {

    set { // On attempt to set new value for the dictionary
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "AppSettings")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    get { // On attempt to get something from dictionary
        if let settings = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppSettings") as? [String: String?] {
            return settings
        } else {
            return [:]
        }
    }}
```

But line `if let settings = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppSettings") as? [String: String?]` causes warning:

> Cast from '[Any]?' to unrelated type '[String : String?]' always fails

Any ideas how to save this dictionary in UerDefaults?

Comment: Why are the values of your dictionary optional strings?  You would normally just omit the key and therefore have `nil` returned when accessing that key, so you would use `[String:String]`

Comment: `UserDefaults` is widely Objective-C based. In ObjC dictionaries `nil` values are not supported anyway.

Comment: Got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this

```
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppSettings") as? [String: String?]
```

with

```
UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "AppSettings") as? [String: String?]
```

as you store a dictionary so don't use `.array(forKey` which returns `[Any]?` that for sure can't be casted to `[String:String?]`

---

Also from [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

**synchronize()**

> Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.

so comment

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```